# Should I avoid creating a MongoDB user in the 'admin' database if I do not intend to grant it cluster level roles

Tags: mongodb, security

The MongoDB documentation indicates that a user can be created with any database as its authentication database. Is there any reason I would choose to create my user in the 'admin' database, unless I intended to grant it cluster level privileges?

Should I avoid creating users in the **'admin'** database unless the above criteria applies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the user is stored does not influence what privileges are granted to the user.

If you prefer to have all users defined in the same place, it makes sense to keep them in the admin database.

If your users have access to one database each and you prefer to have users defined in the database that they have access to, it could make sense to define them in the database they have access to.

In either case which databases the users have access to, and what  operations they are allowed to perform, can be defined per user.

If you store users in admin database, but the client is connecting to another database, the `authSource` must be [explicitly specified when connecting](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-authentication/#auth-source).

Comment: The admin database is referenced in relation to cluster level roles several times in the docs :

"Cluster Administration Roles:
The admin database _includes the following roles for .._"

and 

"MongoDB provides the built-in database user and database administration roles on every database. MongoDB _provides all other built-in roles only on the admin database._"

Based on your explanation above, does 'include...' and 'provides...' mean "Can only be **granted** on the admin database _resource_?".

Comment: Where a user is defined and where roles are defined don't have to be the same. The built-in roles are defined in the admin database, they can be used by users defined in other databases. Some operations can only be *performed* on admin database, I am not sure if this is what you saw.

Comment: Yes sounds like it, that all makes sense. Thanks for your help.